# express ejs form sending undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, undefined, ejs

I know this might be a dumb question but I can't seem to solve this. I'm trying to create a url-shortner with Node, Express and Ejs. But my ejs form is sending undefined values.

Here's my ejs:

```
<div>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<form action="/api/redirect" method="POST">
    <label>Enter Url Please</label>
    <input type="text" name="url" id="" value="<%= url.url %> ">
    <button type="submit">Redirect</button>
</form>
```

and this is my router:

```
const express = require('express');
const URLs = require('../models/urls')
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/',  (req,res) =>{
res.render("index", {url: new URLs()})  
})

router.post('/redirect', (req,res) =>{
let url = req.body.url
console.log(`Value passed = ${url}`)
res.redirect(`http//${url}`)
})
module.exports = router;
```

these are the errors I'm getting:

[image: Chrome Error]

[image: Terminal Error]

Any help would be great, Thank you! c:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your `url` variable is `undefined`. That causes the error message you see in your browser. It may be because `req.body.url` is not defined. That could have a number of reasons in turn. Maybe you're looking for the `url` field on the wrong object. Or maybe you're missing some package that will make the field available in the first place, such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser).

Additionally, you're missing a colon in the protocol: it needs to say `http://${url}` instead of just `http//${url}`.

Lastly, it looks like you want to *redirect* to some URL, not render a template, in which case you would presumably call `res.redirect` or some equivalent instead of `res.render` (I forget the exact Express-API specs).

The whole line should look something like:

```js
res.redirect(`http://${url}`)
```

Comment: I tried changing the vars names, it didn't changed anything. :c

and I was rendering an a error view here, forgot to change it to redirect while posting

Comment: Have you installed body-parser?

Comment: ok that was it. I forgot about body-parser, Thank you soo much! c: